# How to add the same ActionBar in all the activities And how to show the navigation drawer in all activities

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I have created an app with navigation drawer which I want to show on all the activities. And I want to show the same `actionbar` how can i do it?

I had created my app in android studio with

```
     minSdk =15 
and TargetSdk=23
```

And how can I fetch the email id of the user in navigation drawer .

Comment: You should add more details to the question and make independent questions separate questions.

Comment: What details you want?

Comment: What have you done so far? If you can share the code, one can help you. If you're looking to learn, a tutorial would be helpful.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Srinivas which files code you want to see? Navigation drawer - it contains 3 xml files and 1 main activity file i cant post all the code

Comment: Please share what you already have done

Comment: mention with code you have integrated and tested so far to get you desire

Answer (score 0):

The better way is , You have to implement fragment instead of seprate activities but if you have implemented activities and you don not want use fragment than you have to create a java class for navigation drawer and call the same class in each activity and also include the view in each activity but it is not good practice.

Comment: can you give me some tutorial which can explain me this in better way and i have created navigationdrawer which is already present in the list of the blank activity

Comment: check sharelock bar lib for action bar  http://www.necronet.info/2011/09/learn-to-use-sherlock-actionbar-on.html  and for second way i don't have any tutorial it is totaly mannual task :)

Comment: I am using android studio